# PyTorch Batch masked select implementation

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

How can I perform a *batched* [`masked_select`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.masked_select.html)?

Given:

```
x = torch.tensor([[1., 2., 2., 2., 3.],
                  [1., 2., 4., 3., 2.]])
```

The desired output would be:

```
tensor([[1., 3., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 4., 3., 1., 1.]])
```

Here is a possible approach:

```
x = torch.tensor([[1., 2., 2., 2., 3.],
                  [1., 2., 4., 3., 2.]])

ones = torch.tensor([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
                     [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])

masks = torch.tensor([[ True, False, False, False,  True],
                      [ True, False,  True,  True, False]])

for i in range(x.size(0)):
    mask = masks[i]
    s = torch.masked_select(x[i], mask)
    ones[i][:s.size(0)] = s
```

Are there any alternative solutions?

Comment: @ivan  I see you have encountered similar problems. Do you have a solution? Thank you！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with those kinds of problems is that the intermediate result is non-homogenous: in your batch elements will have different numbers of masked values. This is an issue if we want to apply PyTorch builtins. Here I am providing two solutions to perform this operation.

---

#### 1- Using a [*list* comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Go through the batch elements, mask and pad by the appropriate amount:

```
>>> pad = lambda v: F.pad(v, [0, len(m)-len(v)], value=1)
>>> torch.stack([pad(r[m]) for r, m in zip(x, masks)])
tensor([[1., 3., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 4., 3., 1., 1.]])
```

This is rather straightforward and similar to your approach.

---

#### 2- Using [`torch.scatter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_.html#torch.Tensor.scatter)

A vectorized alternative is to construct the correct value and index tensors such that we can apply `torch.scatter` and obtain the desired result. The trick here is to work with flattened tensors. From `x` and `masks` we first want to get access to `nz` and `idx` defined as:

- `nz`: the non-masked values from `x` (using `masks` of course), *i.e.* we need to find:

  ```
  tensor([1., 3., 1., 4., 3.])
  ```
- `idx`: their corresponding indices in the output tensor *when flattened*.

  ```
  tensor([ 0,  1,  5,  6,  7])
  ```

Then we can apply scatter with something like `out = ones.scatter(dim=0, idx, nz)` which will effectively perform: `out[idx[i]] = nz[i]`.

To construct `nz`, we can directly index `x` with `masks`indices of non-zero values using  on `masks`:

```
>>> nz = x[masks]
tensor([1., 3., 1., 4., 3.])
```

For `idx` it will be a little bit more tricky. We can sort the mask itself, flatten it and get the non-zero values using [`torch.Tensor.nonzero`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nonzero.html). When sorted, the `True` values end up at the beginning of each rows:

```
>>> idx = masks.sort(1, True).values.view(-1).nonzero()[:,0]
tensor([ 0,  1,  5,  6,  7])
```

Finally we can apply `torch.scatter` and reshape to get the desired result:

```
>>> torch.ones(x.numel()).scatter(0, idx, nz).view_as(x)
tensor([[1., 3., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 4., 3., 1., 1.]])
```

*The usage of `torch.scatter` here is limited since the inputs are one-dimensional. An equivalent approach is to simply to:*

```
>>> o = torch.ones(x.numel())
>>> o[idx] = nz
>>> o.view_as(x)
```

Complete approach:

```
>>> idx = masks.sort(1, True)[0].view(-1).nonzero()[:,0]
>>> torch.ones(x.numel()).scatter(0, idx, x[masks]).view_as(x)
tensor([[1., 3., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 4., 3., 1., 1.]])
```